# Importing data older than last transaction into datomic

Tags: time, transactions, datomic

Am I understanding this correctly?

http://docs.datomic.com/transactions.html

> You can set :db/txInstant explicitly, overriding the transactor's
>   clock time. When you do, you must choose a :db/txInstant value that is
>   not older than any existing transaction, and not newer than the
>   transactor's clock time. This capability enables initial imports of
>   existing data

Does this mean I can't add facts into datomic that are older than last transaction in a way that the queries as-of will work?

This seems to be a huge restriction. What to do when I interface with other system? For example I may get data about order from yesterday, but clerk only got time to enter it into system today. If somebody entered any facts today I won't be able to add that old data?

Is adding an explicit time attribute and using it in all queries the only option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, when you have an application-driven notion of time i.e. the "recorded" time at which some event that you are transacting "now" occurred, you also need an application-driven query mechanism. Look at a similar [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/datomic/complects%2420time/datomic/zDoFsxKgARQ/6SWomlpYYB0J) in the Datomic google's group.

So the answer is yes, you'll have to explicitly handle that "recorded" time.

Comment: Thanks, this thread was very informative. I'm a little disappointed, for my application datomic is no improvement over relational database with timestamp columns.